# Setting a dark color theme in Eclipse makes the function tooltips unreadable

Tags: eclipse

I've found that setting a dark color theme in Eclipse makes the function tooltips unreadable.

This is probably easiest to describe with a picture:
[alt text http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/9503/blahi.gif](http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/9503/blahi.gif)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: No, Eclipse is too retarded to let us change the colour. This is the only reason I ditched Zend Studio.

Comment: Hahaha... i love a bit of brutal honesty...

Comment: I know it's been a while, any updates on newer version of eclipse?

Comment: Did you try with one of the themes of eclipsecolorthemes? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143#5349143

Comment: It seems there is an Eclipse feature request for this. If you want it fixed, log in and vote for this bug (add yourself to the CC list) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=41867

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i've found is to leave eclipse in normal bright mode, and use an OS level screen inverter.

On OSX you can do command-shift-8 (i think that's the key combo), inverts the whole screen

on linux with compiz, it's even better, you can do windows-n to darken windows selectively. (or windows-m to do the whole screen)

on windows, the only decent solution i've found is powerstrip, but it's only free for one year.. then it's like $30 or something..

then you can invert the screen, adjust the syntax-level colours to your liking, and you're off to the races, with cool shades on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Eclipse in Ubuntu or other environment where it uses GTK+ themes, you can follow [this guide](http://weblog.avp-ptr.de/20120728/how-to-fix-eclipse-colors-for-autocompletion-and-tooltips/) to edit the tooltip and autocomplete colours from outside Eclipse. Not the ideal solution, but it does the trick.