# Eclipse IDE for Java - Full Dark Theme

Tags: eclipse, themes

Is there any way to completely turn Eclipse to a dark IDE?
Here's a [Picture](http://www.matthewimrie.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/OmegaTheme.png) of what I'm asking:

I don't mind doing 1 hour of work to do something like this :D

**EDIT:**

As Konstantin Komissarchik said, I had to modify my OS colors. This is possible by adding a custom Visual Style to the Windows. With the aid of a [Custom Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/) and a [Custom Visual Style for Windows 7](http://jaycee13.deviantart.com/art/Mango-XB-K-Visual-Style-7-244943275) (Which I have changed a little bit), my Eclipse looks like the picture below:
[image: Screenshot of my Eclipse]

### Update 2019:

The latest versions of Eclipse now come with a dark theme. Just go to `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Theme` and select "Dark" or another appropriate version based on your operating system.

[image: Eclipse default dark theme]

Of course you can still enable dark visual styles to your Windows or change your theme on other operating systems but the default dark theme is good enough for the most part.

Comment: I already read [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96981/color-themes-for-eclipse). The themes provided in the website and the plugin just change the editor's theme not the whole application.

Comment: I don't know about the latest versions of the Eclipse but for the version I use, it's not possible. The picture I have uploaded is with the aid of a custom Visual Style.

Comment: Does the Placebo theme override all other themes or is it something you can revert on the fly? The fact I'm overriding libraries to install it is the only thing keeping me from doing this.

Comment: I'm not currently using the Placebo VS. I'm using [another one](http://jaycee13.deviantart.com/art/Mango-XB-K-Visual-Style-7-244943275) but the important thing is that using a VisualStyle changes the look of your Windows altogether, not just Eclipse. You can easily go to Personalize settings in Control Panel and change it to the Windows' default theme.

Comment: The image above is created with the custom VisualStyle I've already linked. However, currently I'm using my own modified theme (for editor) + [this amazing theme for Eclipse Juno](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes). If you'd like, I could share my theme too.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori Is there a way to resize the label of the files? With the Dark Juno theme (in Eclipse Kepler), the labels of the files and dialogs became greater than the normal..

Comment: @Overflowh Hmmm. Don't know really. I haven't tried to modify the theme. I used it "as-is". But there's a chance that it is possible.

Comment: Am I the only one who hates grainy icon borders by dark Eclipse themes? I like dark themes in general, but with icons designed for a light gray background Eclipse UI looks defective: round shapes appear as ugly octagons, shadowed text (i.e. perspective names) - blurry and almost unreadable, etc. Because I spent a couple of hours to test a variety of dark themes and has found that all of them suffer from the issue. Hopefully it will save time of others, who cares about such nuances. As for me, Eclipse is not ready for dark themes yet.

Comment: And it is not ready especially on OS X platform, where there is a bunch of other visual problems: not overridable native light gray buttons, tabs, table headers, contrasting white separator lines. Probably that explains why Eclipse does not include any dark theme as a predefined option. A workaround of OS X issues would be either too tricky or not possible at all.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori Thanks a lot. I followed your suggestion and my eclipse now is "almost" perfect. I use the custom theme you provided, but why is the scrollbar is not visible by default? i think its because the scrollbar has a same colour with the background. I need to hover the scrollbar (both in eclipse and windows explorer) to make it visible. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori i use windows 7 64bit so i cant use the .dll provided by the custom theme

Comment: Go to `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Appearance` and choose ‘Dark’. Works for my Eclipse Luna at least.

Comment: A 2019 update would be appreciated to this question.

Comment: @Mike how do you mean? A summary of themes? I'll get to it tomorrow.

Comment: @Mike updated. The new version's dark theme is good enough so I didn't think it's necessary to include other options.

Comment: Why "latest version in 2019"? I mentioned the dark theme shipped with Eclipse as early as Eclipse 4.4 Luna in 2014 ([See my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5349143/6309)).

Comment: @VonC Didn't say "since latest version". Said "the latest versions" meaning last couple of versions it's been coming with the dark theme. I only added that update because Mike wanted a 2019 update.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I missed the 's' in versions.

Comment: FYI, as of Jan 2021 themes are at Window > Preferences > General > On Appearance > Theme

Answer (score 293, accepted):

Moonrise is the best dark theme I have ever seen for Eclipse!
Just follow the steps on the website and Enjoy!

https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme

[image: https://raw.github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/master/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes/screenshot/screenshot-ubuntu_v0.8.2.png]

Comment: Yes moonrise is great. But if you are using CDT, you should also look at this http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=4663 Without it, the text area colors make it hard to read.

Comment: This worked for me on the latest Eclipse (Kepler SR1).  I use it with eclipse color theme plugin for syntax highlighting.

Comment: disappointed, not because of the theme itself but because of its applying-procedures .. when I try to apply it, it gives me very dark and annoying, non-relative colors, ugly (have to say) mix of colors .. it does not look like what i see in this page nor on its web-page .. try to follow their guidance for tuning the colors .. but still looks ugly .. sorry .. it looks pretty nice over here, though I cant see/say the same on/about my machine :-( ..

Comment: This does not seem to work well using whatever flavor of Eclipse came with the android SDK. My line numbers are still all white, some lines in my code are white, most of the text is black on a deep grey background...

Comment: Ubuntu people will get this, but this sucks on Windows unfortunately :(

Comment: there are some problems in debian too, it;s nothing like the picture :(

Comment: It looks great, however, when I have a tab open such as tasks or problems the grid displays as white and can really look out of place. This can affect my OCD horrendously, but never mind I'll get over it. xD

Comment: Didn't really work for me, the background is off black and the majority of code is black so pretty unreadable :(

Comment: If you apply the theme and the code highlighting (linked on the github page) and the Eclipse Chrome Theme settings that are also linked, it actually looks OK on Windows. You might need to change the system theme to one that uses similar colours for windows etc (e.g. http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/7/A/17ABABA3-79C8-4B6D-AA18-384E33D1B055/CommunityShowcaseCityscapes.themepack for win 7 users) but you are 99% of the way there with just the defaults they give you, and there are additional tweeks listed in the troubleshotting that can solve any remainging issues.

Comment: Does not look smooth with XFCE shell

Comment: I have just installed the Moonrise theme and it's great however, my text editor cursor is black - is there anyway to change it to white so it is visible when selecting code?

Comment: The default GIT font settings will destroy your eyeballs when you look in the Project Explorer screen, unless you manually change the font colors for ignored and uncommitted files.  Go to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Appearance -> Fonts and Colours, then to GIT and change those darn font colors.  Black on dark gray... seriously??

Comment: Obsidian is better than DarkMoon in my opinion

Comment: Really buggy for me in Eclipse Mars

Comment: I get a warning saying that Moonrise contains unsigned content. Should I worry abou this?

Comment: Works well in my win7/Luna(4.4.2) environment.

Comment: @ Filth, install eclipse color theme plugin may help, I fixed the same problem with this plugin.

Comment: How much time do you need to get used to the dark theme? I tried various dark themes but all of them disturb my eyes. Too much colors and some of them are hard to read on dark background. Will I get used to it or should I change back to the classic theme?

Comment: I think that this answer is no longer correct. Moonrise UI theme is now part of Eclipse distribution as "Eclipse Dark" (Eclipse Luna+), however it has a lot of troubles and it's not really, really dark, especially on **Windows**. Looks like answer proposed by @MarcinTomiak is the best at present moment. Darkest Dark Theme not only provides good dark experience in **Windows**, but also integrates Editor colors theme and a custom icon set for Dark theme. This is far more than Moonrise or Eclipse Dark has ever accomplished. The Darkest Dark Theme works on Eclipse Neon+.

Comment: very poor contrast choices--lots of black text.

Answer (score 215):

Update August 2016:

[Tejas Padliya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1556613/tejas-padliya) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143?noredirect=1#comment65533392_5349143):

> Dark theme works well with Eclipse 4.5 onward with Windows 10.
>   No more black text on black background

---

Update June 2014:

As mentioned din "[Dark Theme, Top Eclipse Luna Feature #5](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/20/dark-theme-top-eclipse-luna-feature-5/)", [Eclipse 4.4 (Luna)](http://www.eclipse.org/luna/) has a dark theme included in it (see [informatik01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814702/informatik01)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143?noredirect=1#comment37888889_5349143)):

[image: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/darklinux.png]

> When Eclipse 3.0 shipped in 2004 it brought a new look to the workbench. Now, 10 years later, an entirely new Dark Theme is launching.
>
> The theme extends to more than just the Widgets. Syntax highlighting has also been improved to take advantage of the new look.

The [What's new page](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_whatsnew.html&cp=0_6) mentions:

> A new dark window theme has been introduced. This popular community theme demonstrates the power of the underlying Eclipse 4 styling engine.
>   **You can enable it from the `General > Appearance` preference page**.
>   Plug-ins can contribute extensions to this theme to style their own specific views and editors to match the window theme.

---

Update April 2013:

It seems the solution below don't work well with Eclipse Juno 4.2 and Windows 8, according to [Lennart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368354/lennart) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143?noredirect=1#comment22521072_5349143).

One solution which (mostly) work is the **[Eclipse Chrome Theme](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme#.UV6k_qJQnXs)** (compatible Juno 4.2 and even Kepler 4.3), from the GitHub project **[eclipse-themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes)**, by [Jeeeyul Lee](https://github.com/jeeeyul).

[This post](http://hoogli.com/items/Light_on_Dark_Eclipse_4.2_%28Juno%29_Themes.html) mentions:

> **The first is to change the appearance of what is inside the editor windows**.
>   That can be done with the Eclipse Colour Theme plugin (http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/). My favourite editor theme is Vibrant Ink with the Monaco font. They explain how to install their themes very well (http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=how-to-use), although you get a fine set of dark themes with the default plugin install and may not need to come back to their website for any more. Get the plugin here.
>
> **The second stage is darkening the chrome of the UI, which is all the widgets and menus and everything outside of the child window canvases**.
>   This plugin gives you a GUI editor for the chrome colour scheme: https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/.
>   If you want a dark one, go ahead and click away until eclipse is dark.
>
> Once you are done, some GUI surface area will show through the system theme as mentioned at the top of this post.
>   Rather than using that editor, you could install the pre-baked Dark Juno theme instead.
>   The install is manual.
>   Start by downloading it from here: https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes.
>   It has to be copied into your eclipse dropins folder. This lives next to the eclipse executable, not in your workspace or someplace like that. In my case the command to do the copy was:

```
cp ./plugins/com.github.eclipsecolortheme.themes_1.0.0.201207121019.jar /usr/lib/eclipse/dropins/
```

> You could be running eclipse from any directory though, so which eclipse will tell you where it should go.
>   Restart eclipse and you should find a Dark Juno option under `Preferences::General::Appearance`. It is a nice neutral grey with some gradients and is a very good option.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Update December 2012 (20 months later):

The blog post "[Jin Mingjian: Eclipse Darker Theme](http://jmj-eclipse.blogspot.com/2012/12/eclipse-darker-theme-and-sorry-to.html)" mentions this [GitHub repo "**eclipse themes - darker**"](https://github.com/jinmingjian/eclipse.themes.darker):

[image]

> The big fun is that, the codes are minimized by using Eclipse4 platform technologies like **[dependency injection](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/Dependency_Injection)**.
>   It proves that again, the concise codes and advanced features could be achieved by contributing or extending with the external form(like library, framework).
>   New language is not necessary just for this kind of purpose.

---

Update July 2012 (15 months later):

I have seen one! (Ie, a fully dark theme for Eclipse), as reported by [Lars Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548637/vogella) in "[Eclipse 4 is beautiful – Create your own Eclipse 4 theme](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/11/eclipse-4-is-beautiful-create-your-own-eclipse-4-theme/)":

[image: Eclipse fully dark theme]

> If you want to play with it, you only need to write a plug-in, create a CSS file and use the **`org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme`** extension point to point to your file.
>   If you export your plug-in, place it in the “dropins” folder of your Eclipse installation and your styling is available.

[pixeldude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310236/pixeldude) mentions in the comments having publish ["Dark Juno" on GitHub](https://github.com/rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes)!

[Komododave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/490127/komododave) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143#comment16403778_5349143) that you don't always need a plugin: see "[Ubuntu + Eclipse 4.2 - Dark theme - How to darken sidebar backgrounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238773/ubuntu-eclipse-4-2-dark-theme-how-to-darken-sidebar-backgrounds/12238896#12238896)" for an example, based on gtkrc resource.

---

Original answer: March 2011

Note that a full dark theme will be possible with e4.
(see [dynamic css with e4](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-40-rcp-dynamic-css) or [A week at e4 – Themeing in e4](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2010/04/26/a-week-at-e4-themeing-in-e4/)):

[image: dark theme extension]

[image: full dark theme]

In the meantime, only for editors though (which isn't what you want but still merit to be mentioned):

[**www.eclipsecolorthemes.org**](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/):

> "Fresh up your Eclipse with super-awesome color themes!"

[image: themes for editors]

Comment: I've released Dark Juno, the theme you mentioned above on github. https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes

Comment: @pixeldude Excellent. I have edited the answer to include your project, for more visibility.

Comment: You don't need to write a plugin yourself to get eclipse looking like this, simply install Roger Dudler's Dark Juno theme as prescribed on his github project readme, then follow my customisation tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238773/ubuntu-eclipse-4-2-dark-theme-how-to-darken-sidebar-backgrounds/12238896#12238896

Comment: Eclipse 4.2.1 on Mac: Dark Juno blackens the UI _except_ the Java Editor - to get it black, I installed the Eclipse Color Themes as well.

Comment: @ignis interesting. So *two* theme mechanisms are needed then.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these work properly with Eclipse 4.2.2 and Win8. Either some parts remain unskinned (e.g. the breadcrumb bar) or look ugly (tab headers). And the Dark Juno Theme seems to be abandoned :(

Comment: @Lennart that is unfortunate. Let me know if you find an alternative.

Comment: @VonC the closest thing I could find was this (http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-chrome-theme) extension for eclipse, it lets you fiddle with the color a lot of elements, but I was unsuccessful making a full dark theme. At least it's a bit more pleasing to the eyes than the default theme.

Comment: @Lennart ok, I have found a post which might help. See my edited answer.

Comment: @VonC Justin Ribeiro has a [blog post](http://justinribeiro.com/chronicle/2013/05/10/making-eclipse-4-2-a-little-darker-with-css-and-eclipse-color-themes/) with handy css rules for styling E4. I have sampled a couple of those into the CSS editor in Jeeyuls chrome theme and have with very little hassle gotten the result I was after http://min.us/lbtOI5QF15Hu2k

Comment: @ccondrup looks good! Let me know if you can make the IDE *completely* black, and I will include both the blog post and your example in the answer.

Comment: Juno (4.2), Windows 7: the "Dark Juno" plugin has some bugs.  For example, the Maven POM Editor tabs are not displayed.  Deal breaker, unfortunately.

Comment: @Joe Coder confirmed, same with me

Comment: @VonC On the updated post on april 2013,  i followed all the steps, but when I try to unzip the file to dropin file in my eclipse file, it says that .zip file is invalid. I also tried to extract the files within the file and copy them over, but the dark juno theme didn't show up.

Comment: @Bbvarghe strange... can you copy in a comment the exact url of that zip file, for me to test?

Comment: @VonC here is the link:
https://github.com/downloads/rogerdudler/eclipse-ui-themes/com.github.eclipsecolortheme.themes_1.0.0.201207121019.zip

i opens up zip file in my temps with nothing in it.

I also tried the "download zip link" with url:
https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes/archive/master.zip

Comment: @Bbvarghe yes, downloads are now removed (https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads). Releases are a good replacement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5207352/6309. You can open an issue in rogerdudler's repo asking for a release file.

Comment: @VonC In your last update you mention a post which says to install both jeeeyul and Dark Juno theme, it recommends you to customize it using jeeeyul and after install the other one. However, in practice you can choose only a theme in *Preferences->General->Appearance*, so it doesn't make full sense to install both of them, does it? By the way, for me the Dark Juno Theme looks very dark and ugly, I'll personally go with jeeeyul and customized dark grey, even if some views remain still wait.

Comment: @XtremeBiker true, I didn't test that last post, but I am not sure if the two themes are installed the same way.

Comment: Actually they don't need to be installed the same way, as you can install the first one from update sites and for the second one you need to copy zip's content into *dropins* directory. However, if you check usage guides for [jeeeyul](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/) and [dark-juno](https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes) you'll see both of them have incompatible setting up requirements. However, the link from the answer from @guari says it would be a requirement to have jeeeyul installed for ui-themes, don't know..

Comment: @XtremeBiker in my theme, jeeeyul plugin is needed because I'm using its `swt-tab-renderer` for `CTabFolder` element, nothing else. The differences from the native one are little: it provides a darker icon for 'X' to close the tab, a more transparent texture for the hovered tab and an option to use a gradient as background for selected tab. In my last update I uploaded also a package that doesn't need external plugin, may be in next update I'll embed a class that provides a custom `swt-tab-renderer` directly in my theme if I find how to do that..

Comment: Seems like with the official release of [Eclipse Luna (4.4.0)](http://www.eclipse.org/luna/) a new update for your post is needed: now the [dark theme](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/20/dark-theme-top-eclipse-luna-feature-5/) comes with Eclipse (no additional actions needed). Here what the official Eclipse documentation says: [What's new in Eclipse Luna?](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html?cp=0_6)

Comment: @informatik01 that looks great! I have included those references in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: For those running Eclipse under GNOME 3 with the global dark theme setting on: add `export SWT_GTK3=1` to your `.profile`

Comment: On Windows, in 4.4 with Dark Theme, there are still problems with default font color (which is black) which gives unreadable text and unnoticable UI elements.
E.g. black font color on blackish background color in text editor
E.g. unnoticable triangles for the folder-arrow-opener in Project Explorer
Apparantly, after 2 hours of searching, it is unfixable for windows.

Comment: dark theme works well with Eclipse 4.5 onwards with Windows 10. No more black text on black background

Comment: @TejasPadliya Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC In Eclipse dark theme, the class names in the packaged structure is not clearly visible. How to fix this. I am using Eclipse Neon 2

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya Five years later, I am not sure: it is best to ask a new question, with the exact configuration used for your block theme.

Answer (score 27):

UPDATE 2: A fork of this plugin has been merged with the main Eclipse Platform. You should find it pre-installed in the future Eclipse releases ;)

---

UPDATE: I released a new version, it's a little bit darker, now pretty everything that can be currently modified has been aligned to the theme colors. Have fun!

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

---

if you may like, I uploaded on github a dark theme I made some months ago to avoid blinding my eyes when spending many hours on the editor.. I made it because with all the others themes some Eclipse parts remains ugly and unstyled.

You can find it here: http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/

With my Eclipse configurations works quite ok, if you'll find some elements that remains unstyled you can submit an issue or suggest a change and I'll try to correct it if it's possible ;) (remind that currently, CSS styling support in Eclipse it's uncomplete and sometimes buggy..)

Comment: Great to hear that this will come as a part of the Eclipse package. Awesome! Love the theme. Out of interest, what colours do you use for content assist background/foreground?

Comment: If you import the .epf file linked in the README, you will have automatically the right colors for ContentAssist and many other parts ;). You can see the settings by opening that file with a text editor.

Answer (score 19):

There is a completely new, free plugin which is really DARK, supports Retina and has beautiful icons.

What is most important: It doesn't suck on **WINDOWS**! It doesn't have white scrollbars and other artifacts. It's really dark.

You'll find it there:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme

This is how it looks like on Windows 10 with Retina screen:

[image]

Comment: THIS MESSED UP MY ECLIPSE INSTALLATION. Deep s..t

It suck in every way

Answer (score 13):

Here is my Black Eclipse Custom CSS for Chrome Theme Plugin. Usable with eclipse 4.2 and 4.3. Main goal was to make it look nice in ubuntu, besides making it "darker".

Caution: May or may not work on Windows Systems, only checked with ubuntu.

Required: Chrome Theme and Color Theme plugin

1. Install those mentioned plugins. They can be found in the eclipse marketplace.
2. Install my variant of Gedit Oblivion Theme in Color Theme and activate it. (http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=12544)
3. Insert the custom css in css editor of Chrome Theme. I spend several hours with CSS Spy to find out all the relevant information to make eclipse as black and this file as small as possible. There is also an .epf File for the Chrome Theme plugin preferences you should import.
   You can get it from my dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ye5tosl3cjhx96d/yL-_Y5j1PE

In the end your eclipse will look like this:
[image: Black Eclipse running in ubuntu]

Have Fun!

Comment: thx, what I may have missed out here are some tweaks and setting in Chrome Theme, but I am sure anyone who messes with this, will find out which strings to pull. (I remember that I changed the font to ubuntu mono and got rid of shadows with a checkbox in Chrome Theme)

Comment: On Win7 this seems to have the same symptoms as described by @Joe Coder

Comment: I do not use Maven, sry. On a quick view, everything is fine with POM Editor in Kepler, but POM Editor is not working at all in my old Juno Install (Maven is installed).. Maybe it is a Juno problem? Or Windows? I can only recommend to use an superior OS when developing. :D (joking! windows is totally fine for developing!)

Comment: If your goal is to have everything white on black as can be seen in your screenshot then it's very easy.. you can obtain it by putting only one css line: `* { background-color:black; color:white; }` ;) then add only the few relevant rules to style the tab with a gradient. Instead, if you want to set different colors for more elements then things will become harder and really annoying, since lots of bugs in e4 render will pop up...

Answer (score 11):

- Help → Install New Software.
- Enter Eclipse Color Theme Plugin URL: http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/update
- Install Eclipse Color Theme Plugin.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Goto Window → Preferences → General → Appearance → Color Theme
- I like the Havenjark default Color Theme. Eclipse Color Theme Plugin comes loaded with 24 default Color Themes and option to Import a theme.
  [image]

Answer (score 9):

Install a newer version of Eclipse, (**Luna Release (4.4.0)** or more recent), it include a great Dark theme by default.

Here is a screenshot :

[image: Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 Dark Theme]

Comment: There are still some light gray elements like droplists, scroolbars (vertical and horizontal), title bar of logcat, buttons, menu bar.. ;( and simple change of these in windows is not possible ;(

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse uses native OS controls for most UI aspects (buttons, menus, lists, etc.). That's where colors for most of the IDE come from. The first step in making a "dark IDE" is to modify your OS color theme. Then you can add the color themes plugin to complete the look.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a dark theme (Placebo) for my Windows 7 and right now its really heaven for my eyes!! Very cool theme.

Comment: Cool. Could you post a screen capture of the finished result (os+eclipse)?

Answer (score 5):

Its Simple.just Download this file [DarkJuno Theme](http://bit.ly/1dVhLJp).Then Extract the rar file and copy `com.github.eclipsecolortheme.themes_1.0.0.201207121019.jar` file to `/yourEclipsHome/dropins`.

Then restart Eclips and go to `window/preference/General/Appearance`.In there choose `Dark Juno` theme on Dropdown. Thats it. Restart Your Eclips.

For More Info watch this video [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVKdqevQRhg)

Answer (score 5):

If the purpose of a dark theme is to make your eyes comfortable, you can enable High Contrast settings of your Operating System. For example in Windows 8.1 you can turn on - off High Contrast by pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>left SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>PRINT SCREEN</kbd>

This will make entire OS in dark mode, not only eclipse. Below is a sample screenshot of Eclipse with High Contrast enabled

[image]

Comment: High contrast is good on eyes but extremely ugly. As a normal person, I won't need to use that but I usually use modification such as visual styles and registry hacks for my OS.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in ubuntu 12+ get compiz settings manager, in accessibility enable negative, set the shortcuts. The default is super+n. Now make eclipse be in focus and press the super+n or the key you set it as. This will apply negative filter on eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I've build a win 7 dark theme base on the popular windows 7 'concave 7' theme for eclipse dark juno theme.
And I also create a dark theme inspired from the editor color theme 'Zenburn' created by Janni Nurmin

Here are photos of this theme:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/114921213517944089128/albums/5952793008016527457

All settings of this theme is available on github:
https://github.com/youjenli/dark-theme-for-win7-eclipse

And feedback and suggestion is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Man Thank you!! I expend hours trying to find a decent Windows 7 Dark Theme, This concave 7 I tried to download but the source wasn´t avaliable any more. This Theme of your is pretly suitable, THank you.

Answer (score 3):

For a Visual Studio 2013 Dark Theme:

Combine [this preferences file from eclipsecolorthemes.org](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=25999) (an .epf) with the built-in dark theme from Eclipse Luna. I was able to do so with the following steps:

1. Window > General > Appearance > Theme: Dark.
2. File > Import > General > Preferences > Browse: theme-25999.epf > Finish.

[An example search for more VS Dark Themes on eclipsecolorthemes.org](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&q=visual%20studio%20dark)

Answer (score 2):

I've spent few hours looking for a nice solution to make my eclipse UI dark, and I have finally found a way to do it. I am using ***Fedora 18 and Eclipse for PHP Developers*** (PDT v3.0.2).

The nicest solution is to download ***DeLorean Dark Theme*** then enabling it in Gnome Shell.

Installation procedure:

1. Download DeLorean-Dark-Theme-3.6 vs.2.56 from http://browse.deviantart.com/art/DeLorean-Dark-Theme-3-6-vs-2-56-328859335
2. Unzip the archive, and copy the delorean-dark-theme-3.6 folder to /usr/share/themes/
3. Open Gnome Tweak Tool Enable the freshly installed theme from Theme > Gtk+ Theme (If gnome-tweak-tool isn't installed, install it using yum install gnome-tweak-tool, then F2 or launch it from the terminal)
4. Reload Gnome Shell by hitting F2, then typing 'r'
5. Open Eclipse PDT and enjoy the new look
6. I highly recommend to pick one of the nice code coloring themes from *eclipsecolorthemes [DOT] org*   I am using a custom version of the ***Oblivion*** theme by Roger Dudler

Here is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx7m6.png

---

This procedure is for Eclipse PHP and Aptana 3. If you are using Eclipse 4 and higher, I recommend DeLorean Dark Theme for eclipse: http:// goo [DOT] gl/wkjj8

Answer (score 2):

There is pretty simple and easy solution to this problem) Just few simple steps that will transform your ugly Eclipse into fully darked beast)

[example of full darked Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Q12T.png)

**No heavy work or manually editing files required!**

At least this works with the last Eclipse (Mars 2) on Ubuntu 14.04 (though i think such process should work on all OS's)

**So:**

1. Download some dark GTK theme

   for example, you can grab few from http://www.noobslab.com/
2. To apply your newly installed theme you will need Unity tweak tool

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool

   sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-service
   ```
3. Launch Unity tweak - Appearance - Theme - apply your dark theme
4. Open Eclipse; in preferences choose GTK theme
5. In Eclipse, open Marketplace and install Color Theme - you will be able to change editor background and highlight colors to match your dark theme
6. Close Eclipse
7. Go to Eclipe folder:

   ../Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.ui.themes_WHATEVER_NUMBER_HERE/

   in that folder rename or delete 'css' folder
8. Open and enjoy fully darked Eclipse!

PS: install a few dark themes and try which will suit you more

Answer (score 2):

Instead if finding a night theme I found a utility that puts my entire desktop into night mode [NegativeScreen](https://zerowidthjoiner.net/negativescreen).

[image: eclipse ide night mode]

I use the below adjusted 'Smart Inversion Alt 2' matrix where the black is lightened a little.

```
Smart Inversion Alt 2b (danielsokolowski)=
{  0.390, -0.620, -0.620,  0.000,  0.000 }
{ -1.210, -0.220, -1.220,  0.000,  0.000 }
{ -0.160, -0.160,  0.840,  0.000,  0.000 }
{  0.075,  0.075,  0.075,  1.000,  0.000 }
{  1,  1,  1,  0.000,  1.000 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a new plugin which provides full theming for Eclipse:

http://brainwy.github.io/liclipse/

It's integrated with Eclipse Color Theme so that when a new theme is selected in preferences > general > appearance > color theme, the proper background is also applied to other parts of the IDE (theming everything or just views which are previously registered according to a combo in that same page).

And besides theming it provides a bunch of other things :)

Comment: buttons and scrollbars as well?

Comment: Some things are not themeable, but the latest version themes the editor scrollbars (but only that one, not the ones in the trees/tables).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this great theme from above and add predefined theme only for editor from this site:

http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

(I use guari and retta and I think that looks real good :)

I hope that it will  help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Darkest Dark is the best dark theme.
It also comes with different toolbar icon shapes. Here's the link :

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme

Hope you like it.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows 10 users

If you want to get a custom window title color on Windows 10, in short going from this

[image: eclipse - white window title]

to this (or any other custom color for the window of your Eclipse IDE)

[image: eclipse - full black]

follow the next steps.

Go to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\`. Duplicate the folder `aero` and the file `aero.theme`. If you can't duplicate the folder and the file then right click on both, Properties, Security, Modify, add your user to Permissions, and set authorizations to modify, read and write.

Rename the folder `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero - copy` and the file `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero - copy.theme` to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\custom` and `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\custom.theme` (you can pick the name you want).

[image: themes folder]

Rename `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\custom\aero.msstyles` to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\custom.msstyles`.

[image: custom theme folder]

Rename `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\custom\%your_locale%\aero.msstyles.mui` (%your_locale% is fr-FR in my case) to `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\custom\%your_locale%\custom.msstyles.mui`.

[image: custom theme - locale folder]

Edit `custom.theme` with Notepad and change the `PATH` variable of `VisualStyles` to your `custom.msstyles`.

[image: changing theme path]

Set your custom theme (yet unchanged) by double-clicking on `custom.theme`. Then right-click on start menu button, go to Parameters -> Customize appearance -> Themes and select the second one. Go to the menu `Colors`, select dark mode for every applications. Choose custom color for accent color and put it full black.

[image: start menu - parameters]

[image: choosing custom theme]

[image: changin custom theme]

[image: custom accent color]

[image: custom accent color set to black]

Apply your favorite dark theme (here DevStyle - Darkest dark - Deep black) to Eclipse and voilà, you have a full dark theme for Eclipse on Windows 10!

[image: eclipse - full black]

Answer (score 0):

For Mac,

> **Eclipse > Preferences > Appearance > Theme**