# Using Dark Eclipse Color Theme and Comparison Editor

Tags: eclipse, colors, themes

I am using eclipse color theme plugin to have a dark background. (http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/). The plugin works really great. One problem I have is that dark backgrounds look terrible with eclipse's comparison editor. For example, added lines have a dark blue highlight, which does not show up well at all on dark back grounds. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `Window > Preferences > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Text Compare` You can change the colours there, also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

BullfrogBlues had the correct answer in his comment. You can change the colors for the comparison editor at `Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Text Compare`.

The outgoing change color works as an overlay:
[image]

Comment: How about the background of text compare? It is still black in my case. How do I change that? I could only change `Outgoing change color`, which is the outline of the comparison color.

Comment: post a follow up question...it will get more attention that way ;-)