# eclipse Juno custom workbench colors

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

anybody who knows how to change the colors of workbench views (e.g. Package Explorer) in eclipse Juno (4.2)? How can I use this nice, new CSS styling feature?

For the editors it's available under Preferences - General - Appearance, but I want/need to change the whole workbench theme to darker colors.

Comment: check out [this answer to a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5349143/547020), it might be of help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following the "[Eclipse 4 CSS Styling- Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html) ", you could use the [CSS spy](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html#css_spy) to determine the CSS styles applied to the package explorer, in order to develop your [own theme](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html#css_thememanager) for it.

[image: css spy]

Comment: Ok, so there's no "easy" way for customizing the workbench, like one property to change the background color of all views. So I've to create my own theme and style every widget. But the articel above is a good hint for doing that.

Comment: @chrise Excellent. I wish a CSS section was available at http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/ Right now, it lists only sets of preferences for the code editor view, and doesn't concern any other view.