# Eclipse 4 Juno themes

Tags: eclipse, themes

I ran google/bing search and found only one theme for Eclipse 4 Juno.
I would like to know if any theme site or more theme plugins are there.

I would like to customize the look of it, not only plain editor colors ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As reported by [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/about.html) in "[New Eclipse 4 Chrome Theme – Eclipse 4 get even more beautiful](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/25/new-eclipse-4-chrome-theme-eclipse-4-get-even-more-beautiful/)":

> Checkout https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/ for a new Chrome theme. The update side is listed below and the main website describes the setup and the available customization.

So it is a first example of *complete* (ie "not just editor colors") customization of Eclipse (in addition of [existing dark themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme/5349143#5349143))

[image: screenshot]

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1694500/michael) [proposes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3121658) the following instructions:

> In Eclipse click on `Help / Install New Software` then `add` the following update site to download the theme: https://raw.github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/master/net.jeeeyul.eclipse.themes.updatesite/ ([taken from this page](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2012/07/25/new-eclipse-4-chrome-theme-eclipse-4-get-even-more-beautiful/)).
>   Then check `Jeeeyul's themes` to install it.
>
> After installation you can click on `Window / Preferences / General / Appearance`, then select `Jeeeyul's themes - Chrome Theme` and customize it in `... / Chrome Theme` register.
>   Enjoy the awesome theme :)

Comment: Use [CSS Spy](http://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/eclipse-4-and-the-css-spy/) to work out the classes/ids to use for styling. It's a pity there's nothing below Tree elements. I'd like to make the selected file in the Project explorer more prominent.

Comment: What can we say but: OMG! Ponies!

Comment: If you are using Linux you must install this theme. Eclipse looks awesome!

Comment: Updated: 4 months ago. Will this die as well? I love Eclipse, but it looks damn terrible. Especially if you work in it all day.

Comment: @Vonc  - But how can I set indevidual parts  of ( for example - the Moonlight stand alone theme) - as you can see - I want to change the color of the arrow of the tree : I can't see it until i hover it : http://i.stack.imgur.com/rmCyQ.jpg  I've checked in the css of the theme. couldn't find the right node ( if any : p.s im new to eclipse but been many years in VS)

Comment: @RoyiNamir not sure actually: I suspect it should be linked to a css stylesheet, but I haven't found the exact attribute to set.

Answer (score 3):

take a look http://eclipsecolorthemes.org

Your resource for easy installable eclipse color themes. A growing list of the best and most popular color schemes is available.

Answer (score 1):

First you install the The Eclipse Color Theme Plugin provided by http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

**To install the plugin**, go to Help→Install New Software..., press Add Site and enter Eclipse Color Theme as the name and http://eclipse-color-theme.github.com/ update as the URL. Then select the new entry from the select box labeled Work with, mark Eclipse Color Theme for installation and proceed.

After installation restart eclipse. Then go to Window→Preferences→General→Appereance→Color Theme to change the color theme.