# Aptana UI themes

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, themes, aptana

I just started using Aptana and I'm enjoying it. I like the dark theme that comes on default.

[image: aptana]

There's just one thing. Notice how the editors are nice and dark, but the UI is not? Obviously, Aptana is Eclipse based, so I've been browsing around the net for dark themes for Eclipse's UI.

I found this question with a suitable answer: [Eclipse IDE for Java - Full Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme)

When I try to install one of the themes suggested, I get an error:

```
Missing requirement: Eclipse Darker Theme 1.0.0.201302081116
(eclipse.themes.darker.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201302081116)
requires org.eclipse.osgi.services 3.3.100' but it could not be found
```

Of course, I could just install the dependency, but I have no idea where to look.

**I just want my Aptana to be dark, entirely. What must I do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into a similar issue a couple hours ago with a Magento plugin I wanted to install.

In Aptana, click the "Install new software..." item under the Help menu. Then you'll want to add in the repository url for one the eclipse releases. Juno seems to be the most recent release.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/

Then use type osgi into the filter to see what's available. I would guess the one that isn't "incubating" is your best bet.

cheers