# Eclipse color theme and OS L&F

Tags: windows, eclipse

So I have been trying for a couple of hours to set a dark theme for Eclipse Juno, the blinding white in your face is very tiring and strains the eyes after a short time. I managed to find a theme that darkens eclipse but still a few problems remain.

See image

1. I have no control over the background color of the menubar. Is it possible to change it? I tried everything in Win7 "Window Color and Appearance" but aside from being able to change the fontsize of the window title the colors do not change.
2. I have no control over the fontsize used for the titles in the various view panels of Eclipse, like the projectexplorer or editor.
3. No control over scrollbar color.

These are minor issues but would make the end result of the themes so much better. Is it at all possible to do anything with any of those issues on Win7?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this help for item 2?

The font size for the view and editor titles can be changed in Preferences. Select General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts. In the panel on the right, expand 'View and Editor Folders' and select 'Part title font' then click the 'Edit...' button.

On this subject, this Eclipse Themes plugin is also worth a look:

https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/

Comment: No sadly the font size doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent article about Eclipse theming:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4CSS/article.html

As for the menubar and scrollbar, the aforementioned article states:

> SWT currently has some limitations for styling. For example it is not
>   possible to style menus and table headers. In addition some platforms
>   do not allow the styling of certain widgets, e.g. the Button or the
>   ScrollBar widget.

In order to make these widgets fit nicely you can install custom Windows theme, such as this one: http://vi20rickrmetal12us.deviantart.com/art/Pre-Black-VS-for-Windows-7-180497508 (before you can install a custom theme, you have to patch your system with Universal Theme Patcher or similar tool).

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same wall some time ago. I found this resources very useful at that point:

[A eclipse 4 dark theme](http://blog.rogerdudler.com/post/38229973729/dark-juno-a-dark-ui-theme-for-eclipse-4) described in the blog post of its author. It can be downloaded from github [here](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes/). You can see also the content of the code.

The home of various eclipse themes [here](http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/).

Another stackoverflow quetion dealing with similar problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme).

Currently I am using InteliJ Idea with its darkula theme.

Comment: did you try the custom windows theme together with dark juno as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme)?