# Eclipse Kepler Theme Failure

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, themes

I would really appreciate any kind of help with my problem.
Like you can see in the picture I have a problem with themes in eclipse Kepler. After I added theme to dropins folder in eclipse (I am working on ubuntu) I found out, that it's not fully black like was supposted to be.
I downloaded the theme from:
https://github.com/eclipse-color-theme/eclipse-ui-themes

[image: Eclipse Kepler]

Comment: download eclipse color theme too :)

Answer (score 1):

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15988908/2286117) try this plugin: https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme

It works really better than the one you linked for me.