# Eclipse dark theme arrow color

Tags: eclipse, themes

I was looking at [this dark theme post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme) and applied Moonrise theme on Eclipse Juno. I love everything it lays out except for the expandable arrow color. It's barely visible when my mouse isn't hovered. Does anyone know if this is possible to change?

[image]

Comment: May be you will find its settings in General>Editor or in Java>Editor. Otherwise Its may not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Spyros has mentioned, the author noted that the arrows color is impossible to change which is unfortunate.

Regardless, if you don't mind working under old graphic properties (yay!), the system arrow is replaced with a white box plus sign which makes everything visible. The drawback is, of course, the Windows 7 theme is gone. Found this by accident when trying to solve the performance issue: [Look at Pyree's solution](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/40607-63-windows-detected-performance-slow)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that is not possible due to the limitation of the css engine used to theme eclipse, according to the theme's author. ([github](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme#notes))