# Eclipse dark theme for windows: how to change the color of scroll bars and title bars to dark?

Tags: windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, themes

Is there a dark theme for eclipse for windows which changes the color of scroll bars and menu bar to dark as well?

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme), we can see pretty themes but those are for Mac OS. For Windows, the dark themes look pretty ugly, because of those white scroll bars and title bars etc. really!

[image: Eclipse dark theme for windows]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a dark theme that also changes the color of the scroll bars.

**Darkest Dark Theme**

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme

In addition it said it provides nicer icons than the common ones of dark themes.

> Note that it worked fine on Windows 10 64bits with Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). I do not know if it works well in other versions.
>
> [image: Print dark theme with scroll bars]

-

> The Syntax highlighting I am using is not the native of the theme, but the **[RainbowDrops.epf](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme/blob/master/com.github.eclipseuitheme.themes.plugin/bin/color-scheme/RainbowDrops.epf?raw=true)**. Download RainbowDrops.epf (right click on the link and select Save link as...) and import it with Eclipse built-in Preferences Import (go to File > Import... then select General > Preferences).

Comment: this is a beautiful theme by Genuitec and miles ahead of even the latest dark theme by eclipse.  doesn't anyone have any visual style at the eclipse foundation?  Anyway just a heads up if you use the DevStyle theme some buttons may not work and you will have to switch back to a default theme.  For example switch stream flow 'Add...' button, hopefully they will fix in the near future.

Comment: I tried it on 2018-12 eclipse on a mac, but my scroll bars, and top bar are still bright.

Comment: Nevermind, I had to follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432660/installed-dark-theme-in-eclipse-but-scrollbars-is-still-grey/54815012#54815012 to solve it issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the scrollbars are native OS and we can't change it. 
As for the console you can edit it this way:

Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors: Background colour

Then just choose the colors you want.

Hope this information was helpful. 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the information is useful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the original question was for Windows, but this is seen on Linux also and was frustrating to figure out so posting here.

If having to use the SWT_GTK3=0 workaround on Linux for Eclipse, then it will use Gtk2 and you will see the same problem Solace described.

Here is the Gtk2 theme that worked well for me:
https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-theme
Best is to pull down the git repo to '~/opt/vertex-theme', checkout stable, and then install it by hand. (Don't delete directory so can uninstall later if needed. That's why I say to put it in your user's opt directory.) The .deb version didn't have an updated key and now apt whines about that. *glare

After install then run 'gtk-chtheme' (the Gtk2 theme changer) and you can select it there. That will fix both the bright menu bar at the top and scrollbars in Linux. If Gtk3 works for you with Eclipse, then you probably won't see the theme problem.