# Installed dark theme in eclipse, but scrollbars is still grey

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

I am using **Eclipse Luna(4.4.0)** and trying to make it completely dark. So I Installed a theme plugin:

Eclipse menu -> Help -> Eclipse Marketplace, search "Eclipse Color Theme Plugin"

In “Windows Preferences”, selected the “Dark” theme and

Eclipse menu -> Window -> Preference -> General -> Appearance -> Color Theme,
choosed “sublime Text 2″. Done, I'm just changed everything to “Dark”.

But, **scrollbars is still grey**

[image]

Does anybody know how to make it dark too?

[image]

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: use IntelliJ IDEA. It works.

Comment: It'd better be if you pay for it. On-topic: this screenshot seems with the entire (windows?) shell modified. You might want to search for an entire dark theme for your OS (you can find a lot of them on deviantart.com)

Comment: The scrollbars appear to still be controlled by the OS at this point. For reference of others who visit this question, there is a fix on Ubuntu (set the LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=1 environment variable). As Pieter mentioned, one possible fix on Windows would be to get a dark Windows theme, assuming you're comfortable with changing your entire OS skin. For more info on the Dark Theme's various bugs and offenses, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470710/eclipse-luna-dark-theme-not-completely-dark-like-pictures). They really should not have released this feature at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Installed this one http://alexgal23.deviantart.com/art/SkinPack-Flaty-Win7-450416030 Looks really nice right now!

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse's built in dark theme is very problematic.

Check out the DevStyle plugin from Eclipse marketplace. It creates dark themes up to par with other IDEs like IntelliJ.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/darkest-dark-theme-devstyle

Answer (score 1):

For all mac users out there, you can change it in system preferences:
Apple menu > System Preferences, then click General > Show scroll bars
Select “Automatically based on mouse or trackpad.” i voila :)

Comment: This setting worked for me. However, I had to change it to "when scrolling"

Comment: this does not fix the issue

Comment: "when scrolling" works - "automatically based on mouse or trackpad" does not. Tested on OS X 10.11.6 with Eclipse STS 3.9.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score 0):

1. cmd+space
2. System Preferences
3. General
4. Show scroll bars: "When scrolling" (see screenshot)

In my opinion though, this isn't a great solution because you don't see the scroll bar sometimes and sometimes it still shows the bright grey scroll bar depending on where you put your mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of that scrollbar, enable `Show whitespace characters` in

> Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors