# Convert Visual Studio Theme into CSS

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, fonts

Does Visual Studio offer an option to convert a Visual Studio Theme into CSS?  I'm working on a web site they I'd like to have a 'Visual Studio' look and feel and it would be nice if I didn't have to migrate all of the colors and fonts by hand.

**Update**
Or would it be possible to export a similar IDE theme to css, for example: [Eclipse IDE for Java - Full Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme)

Comment: It's highly unlikely... The *Visual Studio Theme* is not written in CSS, so it would need to literally be re-written...

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Do you know of any tools that would do it?