# How to set a Dark Theme in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, themes

I'm trying to set a Dark Theme (such as Darcula or similar ) in Eclipse Juno (I'm using Windows 7 ). 
I've already tried a theme called MoonRise, but it sets the name of methods black on a grey background ( so make all almost invisibile ), I've tried some other solution but they dind't work, can someone help me to find and install a better Dark Theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme/metrics or https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme

You should import the `RainbowDrops.epf` as preference to get a complete dark theme.

Hope it helps. (Related post - [Eclipse IDE for Java - Full Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053834/eclipse-ide-for-java-full-dark-theme))