# eclipse dark theme, but white toolbars

Tags: eclipse, themes

I tried to switch to dark theme or Moonrise UI theme in Eclipse 4.6.0 .
After I switch, everything adapts to the theme except the toolbars, they still are grey.
I could only find solutions regarding white editor windows, nothing about toolbars.

[image: eclipse dark theme white toolbars]

How can I change it?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19796639/6527256) answer

Comment: thanks for your answer, i already installed monrise, it doesnt affect my toolbars

Answer (score 2):

Solution: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=436753

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
./eclipse
```

It works in my case!

Comment: What am I supposed to do with what you posted? A couple of sentences would go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the link below

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme/metrics

You should import the `RainbowDrops.epf` as preference to get a complete dark theme.

With the above settings the menu bar still remains in gray. However the color of the toolbar changes.

Hope it helps.